# CakePHP: Passing data to plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, registration, user-management

I have installed a plugin ([SignMeUp](https://github.com/voidet/sign_me_up/tree/2.0)) for the user registration, and according to the documentation the registration function inside my User Controller has to look something like this:

```
public function register() {
    $this->SignMeUp->register();
}
```

Looking at the $this->data array inside this function shows that everything is working fine. However, when I use

```
debug($this->data);
```

inside the registration() function of the plugin (the one I just directed my function to), the array is empty. Somehow the data doesn't get passed on. What could be the cause?

Comment: Resolved! This can be solved by replacing all the $this->data occurences in the SignMeUpComponent with $this->controller->request->data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved! This can be solved by replacing all the $this->data occurences in the SignMeUpComponent with $this->controller->request->data

It's a change from Cake 1.3 to Cake 2.x